# Delete a value from a Laravel 5.4 database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, destroy

I'm trying to delete values from my database in Laravel 5.4. Here is my code:

**UserController.php:**

```
public function destroy($id)
{

 $user = User::find($id);
 $user->delete();
 return redirect()->route('user.index');
}
```

**View.blade.php**

```
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="datatable-account"
           class="table table-vcenter table-hover table-condensed table-bordered text-center">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="text-center">Username</th>
            <th class="text-center">Last Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">First Name</th>
            <th class="text-center">Role</th>
            <th class="text-center">Email</th>
            <th class="text-center">Action</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('#datatable-account').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    "ajax": '{!! url('api/user') !!}',
    "columns": [
        {data: 'username', name: 'username'},
        {data: 'lastname', name: 'lastname'},
        {data: 'firstname', name: 'firstname'},
        {data: 'role', name: 'role',
            render: function (data, types, full, meta) {
                if (data == 0){ return 'Admin' } else return 'User';}
        },
        {data: 'email', name: 'email'},
        {data: 'id', name: "id",
            render: function (data, types, full, meta) {
                return '<a href="{{ url('delete')}}" data-method="delete" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-user" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button></a>';
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::post('/delete', ['as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'UserController@destroy']);
```

When I click the button Delete, not an error appears, but the value from the Database is still there. What I'm missing. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: I'm not getting errors unfortunatly. It just don't do the delete.

Comment: Have you tried it without ajax ?

Comment: It seems you have ajax error. Try checking in your console after initializing the delete button.

Comment: have you check your ajax method POST/GET , please set it with POST because your laravel route is in POST. or we have an other solution to set your Laravel route with 'any'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `route` so that the request method is `DELETE` and also append `user_id` as @Rodrane suggested.

```
Route::delete('/delete/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
```

In your `view` then update the delete link to look like this.

```
return '<a href="{{ url('delete'.$id)}}" data-method="delete" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-user" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button></a>';
```

Comment: now it says undefined variable user 
view.php
    return '<a href="{{ url('delete'.$user)}}" data-method="DELETE" 
    button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-user" 
    name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button></a>';
controller.php
     public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete();
        return view ('user.index', compact('user'));
    }

Comment: And make sure you know which `object` your returning in `UsersController` for `show` method because the above error is being triggered in your controller

Comment: @LittlePhild This will fail, because you haven't named the route, so the use of the `route()` helper will not work. You should name your route, or use `url()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I created another controller and used the code

```
<form action="{{route('UserController.destroy',$sub->id)}}" method="post">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
                        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" onclick="return confirm('Se sicuro di voler cancellare il subscriber?');" name="name" value="Elimina">
                    </form>
```

When the $sub variable is a foreach var in the table "datatable-account".
Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score -1):

**Answer is updated**
I think you need update your code like:

*Route.php*

```
Route::get('/delete/{id}','UserController@destroy')->name('delete');
```

*View.blade.php* Just update you delete link code with below given:

```
return '<a href="{{ route('delete', [$id])}}" data-method="delete" button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete-user" name="delete"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button></a>';
```